# Netty SSL and websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, netty

I want to configure SSL for one way websocket, basically server pushes information to the webpage and i need this secured. I have set up the pipeline as follows:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

SSLEngine engine = serverSslContext.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(false);
pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));        

pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("handler", webSocketHandler);
```

my handler:

```
public class WebSocketHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent event) throws Exception {.... }

public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {.... }

}
```

my sslserverContext class:

```
 try {
            // Key store (Server side certificate)
            String algorithm = Security.getProperty("ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm");
            if (algorithm == null) {
                algorithm = "SunX509";
            }

            try {
                KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFilePath);
                ks.load(fin, keyStoreFilePassword.toCharArray());

                // Set up key manager factory to use our key store
                // Assume key password is the same as the key store file
                // password
                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
                kmf.init(ks, keyStoreFilePassword.toCharArray());

                // Initialise the SSLContext to work with our key managers.
                serverContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
                serverContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Error("Failed to initialize the server-side SSLContext", e);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.error("Error initializing SslContextManager. " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            //System.exit(1);
        }
```

my javascript page :

```
        var location =  ws://localhost:8989/websocket;

        ws = new WebSocket(location);
        ws.onopen = function(event) { alert("open"); }          
        ws.onclose = function(event) { alert("closed"); }
```

Every time i try to connect, with ssl configured it calls "channelDisconnected", but never goes any further, the method "messageRecieved" is never called. However if i remove the ssl handler fromt he pipeline everything works fine, i have tried to follow the example :

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx

Anyone got any ideas?

The exception im getting is the following:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 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
```

Comment: I figured out the exception, the error was due to client code not calling with wss. But connection still closes during the handshaking.. my handler is never called...

Comment: You need to call handshake() explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***wss://localhost:8989/websocket*** instead of ***ws://localhost:8989/websocket***. Because you are using SSL which works with wss protocol, secured protocol. If you only want to work with ws protocol, you need to remove the SSLHandler from the pipeline.